# How to use corrplot to get an m x n matrix instead of m x m (two differents sets of variables)

Tags: r-corrplot

I am trying to use corrplot and get an output of an mxn matrix instead of a mxm matrix.

The data frame that I is an 80 x 20 matrix where I want to correlate the 2:6 column with the 7:20 column. The preferred output is thus 5x14. Unfortunately, I cannot find a solution yet.

Someone can help me out?

Answer (score 0):

AS far as I know, you can take the is.corr argument and set it to false in order to see the corrplot as, well, a corrplot, regardless the dimensions.

Sadly I think the clustering methods for this in corrplot doesn't work properly then (Or at least they didn't for my data), since they appear to still see the central diagonal as values of 1.